# Qt inheritance and classes constructors confusion

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance, class-constructors

I am a bit new to Qt C++ and I think there is a small thing I'm missing but can't figure what is it.

I am trying to make a simple Qt C++ application just to get familiar with it, but I face some problem, First, I have the votor class, which is the main application class, and another class which is called recorder, which will be used inside the main votor class. For simplicity, I omitted un-related parts,
Here are the files:

votor.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_votor.h"

#ifndef TSTRECORD_H
#define TSTRECORD_H
#endif

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "recorder.h"


class VOTor : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VOTor(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    recorder xs;

private:
    Ui::VOTorClass ui;

};
```

votor.cpp

```cpp
#include "votor.h"

VOTor::VOTor(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), xs(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    //xs = recorder();

}
```

recorder.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <QDebug> 
#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore/qbuffer.h>
#include <QtCore/qiodevice.h>

#include<QtMultimedia/qaudioformat.h>
#include<QtMultimedia/qaudiodeviceinfo.h>
#include<QtMultimedia/qaudioinput.h>

class recorder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
//  recorder();
    recorder(QObject *parent);
    ~recorder();
        //Some functions related to recording omitted for more focus
private:
      //omitted members for simplicity, just some integers, chars and qt objects not related to problem
```

recorder.cpp

```cpp
#include "recorder.h"

recorder::recorder(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)

{
 //just initializing the omitted members normally
}
//recorder::recorder() {}

recorder::~recorder()
{

}
```

as you see, recorder object is a member inside votor class. Now, I need to call recorder constructor to initialize its parent. Now, I knew I can't just make (inside votor.h)

```
recorder xs(parent);
```

so, 
1- is there a way I can call recorder constructor other than initialization list ?
I want another way as I was more convenient to use recorder xs(..) than initialization list, I feel (just feel) that using initialization list is heavy (not performance-wise but on readability ). I know also I can use dynamic allocation, but I don't want to use it without a good reason for.

2- I have decided to use initialization list to call recorder constructor and pass (Qobject* parent) to recorder. The code is built successfully, but when running, it gives access violation error which I can't figure why...
it gives:
"Access violation reading location 0x7C32F08D."

I think I am missing small thing.. I hope to know what is wrong.

Edit:
as @p-a-o-l-o suggested, the access violation was from the omitted code, So, I am posting it here as I don't know what is the problem in my code:

full version of recoder.h

```cpp
class recorder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    recorder();
    //recorder(QObject *parent);
    ~recorder();
    void record();
    void stop();

public slots:
    void stateChanged(QAudio::State);

private:
    unsigned char state;
    QBuffer* voiceBuffer;
    QAudioFormat* format;
    QAudioDeviceInfo* info;
    QAudioInput* audioIn;

    unsigned char writeWav(QByteArray*);


};
```

and the part causes access violation according to debug mode, which is constructor of recorder class

```cpp
recorder::recorder() : QObject(Q_NULLPTR)
{

    state = 0;
    voiceBuffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
    format->setSampleRate(8000);
    format->setChannelCount(1);
    format->setSampleRate(16);
    format->setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format->setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format->setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    *info =  QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    audioIn = &QAudioInput(*info, *format);
    //audioIn->stateChanged.connect(stateChanged);
    //connect(audioIn, &QAudioInput::stateChanged, stateChanged);
    connect(audioIn, SIGNAL(stateChanged (QAudio::State) ), this, SLOT(stateChanged(QAudio::State)));
}
```

Comment: If a type does not have a default constructor, then you must use the initialization list. Same if the type is declared constant. That way, the compiler can ensure that object are constructed correctly.

Comment: For the access violation, **you should use a debugger** to figure out what your code is doing wrong.  Usually a debugger would stop when the error occurs and by looking at code and variable it help a lot determining the problem. In any case, without code that reproduce the access violation, it would be hard to help.

Comment: The program stops at assembly, which I can't know what is the reason. the only thing I am sure of is that the problem comes from parent in initialization list, as when I changed the code and made record with default constructor, then made the initialization list takes not argument, it worked well.

Comment: You may need to use the initialization list when you attempt to allocate your QObject on the stack, as you are doing here. However, in Qt, it is necessary to allocate your children objects on the heap by putting it in a pointer unless everything will be destroyed at the program end. Go to your Qt help screen, look up ~QObject and read the first warning. If you allocate on the heap then you will have more initialization options

Comment: I think all what you need is change default cnstr declaration of `recorder` to be:   `recorder(QObject *parent = nullptr);` , As I understand you want avoid initialization list, so set default parameters.

Comment: @psimpson,  _in Qt, it is necessary to allocate your children objects on the heap_ ...  not really , the warning does not hold such recommendation ..

Comment: @MohammadAKanan Here is the quote. `Warning: All child objects are deleted. If any of these objects are on the stack or global, sooner or later your program will crash.`

Comment: I bet that the crash is not directly related to using an initialization list. Following Phil1970 advice, please compile your program in debug mode and debug its execution. Another good advice by psimpson is to use dynamic allocation on your QObject members.

Comment: @psimpson, along with the next sentence. That does not mean a recommendation for _auto_ or _dynamic_ memory .. it means child objects should be considered  *before* deleting _QObject_ , for a clean code.

Comment: @MohammadAKanan You have taken a very definitive warning in the Qt docs not to allocate parented objects on the stack or global or you will crash, and redefined it to a meaningless, "child objects should be considered".  Considered how?  Feel free to ignore the warnings in the docs if you like, but it is irresponsible to tell others to do so.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim none of your pointers are valid until you set them to a properly constructed object (and I mean: **use `new`**, because both `info` and `audioIn` initialization attempts are wrong).

Comment: @MohammadAKanan I edited the answer further, but I guess you got it right, already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About **question #1**: as rightfully suggested in comments, a proper constructor for a `QObject`-derived class would have a `nullptr` default argument:

```
recorder(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
```

If you really need that `parent` object to initialize the other members in construction, you have no alternatives and must call that constructor, somehow.

Otherwise, have a no-arguments constructor and initialize the other members there:

```
recorder::recorder() : QObject(Q_NULLPTR)
{
    //just initializing the omitted members normally
}
```

Such a constructor will be invoked automatically, no need of initialization list here.

If you still need a parent for the `recorder` object, give it one in the `VOTor` constructor:

```
VOTor::VOTor(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    xs.setParent(parent);
}
```

About **question #2**: as far as I can see from the code you posted, the access violation have nothing to do with Qt parenting and must be related to the (omitted) code inside the `recorder` constructor.

Just to clear it out: parenting a member object is always safe, since it will go out of scope **before** `~QObject()` gets called, so it will be removed from the children list **before** `~QObject()` could possibly call delete on it.

Taking the OP code as an example, the sequence of destructors is the following:

```
~VOTor()
~recorder() ---> xs is removed from the children list
.
.
.
~QObject() ---> will call delete on all children, but ws is not in the list anymore
```

[Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects) is quite clear about the order of construction/destruction of parents and children: in short, if the child is created on the stack everything will be fine until the child is created **after** the parent.
But, again, if the child happens to be a member of the parent class, it will be fine as well for the reasons mentioned above (even if its construction actually happens **before** its parent's).

Comment: -1 for "parenting a member object is always safe".  I'm not sure what you are trying to say by "member object".  Do you mean parenting an object to its own `this`?  Or do you mean parenting to its own `this.parent`?  Regardless, the statement is wrong.  [The Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) give a specific example where parenting an object on the stack will lead to crashes.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o  I edited my question, u r right the violation from the omitted part. all class members I defined causes violation. I don't know why so I edited my answer adding the omitted part.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/8596/solved-qwidget-assumes-allocation-on-heap-not-stack/4

Comment: @MohammadAKanan Interesting that you chose that particular post.  A better post, from the same discussion is [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/8596/solved-qwidget-assumes-allocation-on-heap-not-stack/9) and all that follows that, which demonstrates with a second example the statement in this answer that, "parenting a member object is always safe" is just simply false.

Comment: @psimpson I edited the answer to clarify further. As stated in the link you posted in your comment, **allocating children on the stack is fine if the right order of construction is followed**. I understand you wanted to *protect* other people from information you deemed *wrong*, but this is not the case (also, people are generally wise and humble enough to **test** things before downvoting answers, or even try to edit them).